# couchDB iOS binary rejected database unknown error

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, couchdb, app-store-connect

We have an ionic app with CouchDB with an AWS back end. Up to October, submissions to iTunesConnect passed.

After this, we are seeing a divergence between Xcode emulators, TestFlight, ad hoc on devices versus the App Store Test Team.

Specifically, we are seeing this error from our logs for the Apple team:

```
{"status":500,"name":"unknown_error","message":"Database encountered an unknown error Unknown error!  Did you remember to enable CORS?","error":true}
```

The normal process has been followed: try to replicate locally then fix. Which we have done several times over now, and the Apple environment keeps on throwing up a unique error that we can't reproduce.

We are trying a second round of Tech Support questions to Apple Developer support (the "get clarification..." option here https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/)

So, other than putting in an absurd amount of logging (almost a line by line 'got here / var dump') - any suggestions welcome as to where to look next.

Xcode 8.1 on El Capitan, ionic 1.7.12,  cordova 6.0.0, pouch 5.0.0, ionic ios platform 4.1.0 (to get around issues with splash screen freeze). Also seen on Xcode 8.2, Sierra, ionic 1.7.14, Cordova 6.1.1.

Our most probable next port of call is upgrading to the latest of ionic, maybe even ionic 2. But this involves a *lot* of effort, and divergence of the codebase as we also have to support WinPhone 8.1.

Our submissions with the same code pass Android and WinPho.

Comment: You probably mean Couchbase Lite/Mobile here, not CouchDB itself?

Comment: Actually it's PouchDB. Currently we're suspecting a stunnel cypher issue as it's only Safari that can't connect and only over certain WiFi links.

Comment: ah sorry, I missed that you actually listed PouchDB there. Since it is Browser HTTP requests, it’s outside of PouchDB’s control, sorry!